# with open as not reading the last chunk of the file

Tags: python, file-io, buffer

I'm trying to read a file piece by piece:

```
def buf_read2(filename, buffer_size):

    with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
        buffer = f.read(buffer_size)

        print buffer  # and do other stuff with it
```

This doesn't read the last chunk of the file. For example, if a file is 129 bytes and I set `buffer_size` to 128, the last byte will not be read.

This old school approach works though:

```
def buf_read1(filename, buffer_size):

    f = open(filename, 'rb')
    while True:
        buffer = f.read(buffer_size)
        if not buffer:
            break

        print buffer  # and do other stuff with it

    f.close()
```

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`with` isn't a loop, so in your first example, `read()` only gets called once.

You still need to include a loop:

```
with open(filename, 'rb') as f:
    while True:
        buffer = f.read(buffer_size)
        if not buffer:
            break
        print buffer  # and do other stuff with it
```